# Should you import all classes you use in Python?

Tags: python, coding-style

Python's lack of static typing makes it possible to use and rely on classes without importing them. Should you import them anyway? Does it matter?

#### Example

**someclass.py**

```
class SomeClass:
    def __init__(self, some_value):
        self.some_value = some_value
```

**someclient.py**

```
class SomeClient:
    def __init__(self, some_class_instance):
        self.some_class_helper = some_class_instance
```

Here, the functionality of `SomeClient` clearly relies on `SomeClass` or at least something that behaves like it. However, someclient.py will work just fine without `import someclass`. Is this ok? It feels wrong to use something without saying anywhere that you're even using it.

Comment: If I understand correctly, this logic would mean importing every module that is used anywhere into your top level program. That feels very wrong to me

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, it's completely ok. `some_class_instance` might be anything, it doesn't have to be an instance of `SomeClass`. You might want to pass an instance that looks just like `SomeClass`, but uses a different implementation for testing purposes, for example.

Comment: +1: Only import what you actually use.  What happens at run time is often an extension of something you imported.  Don't fuss with "import everything to make a static language out of Python".  Instead, use the dynamic nature of Python correctly.

Answer (score 6):

Importing `SomeClass` won't make any difference to how that code works.

If you're worried about making the code understandable, comment the fact that `SomeClient` expects a `SomeClass` instance, and/or document it in the docstring.

If you want to *police* the fact that `SomeClient` requires a `SomeClass` instance, you can `assert` it:

```
class SomeClient:
    def __init__(self, some_class_instance):
        assert isinstance(some_class_instance, SomeClass)
        self.some_class_helper = some_class_instance
```

which *will* require importing `SomeClass`.  But note that you're being rather restrictive there - it precludes using a Mock `SomeClass` for testing purposes, for example.  (There's a lengthy rant about this here: ["isinstance() considered harmful"](http://www.canonical.org/~kragen/isinstance/).)

Comment: I'm definitely not interested in type checking or policing the argument.

Comment: @Daniel: Good! It usually is a bad practice anyway. Prevents code reuse and duck-typing

Answer (score 4):

In this case, you shouldn't import the class.

Python relies on what is called "[duck typing](http://docs.python.org/glossary.html#term-duck-typing)" - if it walks like a duck and quacks like a duck, it might as well be a duck.

Your code doesn't care what class really gets passed in when the program runs. All it cares is that it acts just like "SomeClass" acts.

**duck-typing**

> A pythonic programming style which determines an object’s type by
>   inspection of its method or attribute
>   signature rather than by explicit
>   relationship to some type object (“If
>   it looks like a duck and quacks like a
>   duck, it must be a duck.”) By
>   emphasizing interfaces rather than
>   specific types, well-designed code
>   improves its flexibility by allowing
>   polymorphic substitution. Duck-typing
>   avoids tests using type() or
>   isinstance(). (Note, however, that
>   duck-typing can be complemented with
>   abstract base classes.) Instead, it
>   typically employs hasattr() tests or
>   EAFP programming.

Answer (score 1):

This is a good python code, "we are all consenting adults here", maybe if you expect a class you should include a comment and that's ok.